# C# Error : Data source is an invalid type. It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, idatareader

I update my project `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll` version 4.0.0.0 to 5.0.414.0. Then I got this error. Previously it worked without issue.

**Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.**
**Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details**: System.InvalidOperationException: Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.

```
                this.CategoryDropDownList.DataTextField = "CAT_NAME";
                this.CategoryDropDownList.DataValueField = "CAT_ID";
                this.CategoryDropDownList.DataSource = mgr.GetCategories();// here error occurred 
                this.CategoryDropDownList.DataBind();
```

Inside `GetCategories` method -

```
        public IDataReader GetCategories()
        {
            IDataReader reader = null;

            using (var cmd = MyDB.GetSqlStringCommand(MySqlScriptor.GetSql("QueryCategories")))
            {
                reader = MyDB.ExecuteReader(cmd);
            }

            return reader;
        }
```

`ExecuteReader`always return `IDataReader` object.

I tried to cast `IDataReader` to 'IDataSource'.but it gives me an error like this.

**Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.RefCountingDataReader' to type 'System.Web.UI.IDataSource'.**

```
        public IDataSource GetCategories()
        {
            IDataSource reader = null;

            using (var cmd = MyDB.GetSqlStringCommand(MySqlScriptor.GetSql("QueryCategories")))
            {
                reader = (IDataSource)MyDB.ExecuteReader(cmd);
            }

            return reader;
        }
```

Please provide me a solution. Thank you

Comment: This is a guess as I haven't used the Enterprise Library for a long, long time but you might try getting the `InnerReader` of that `RefCountingDataReader` object. It is also an `IDataReader` so your method signature won't have to change but it might implement `IEnumerable` and thus work in that context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advice from @jmcilhinney might work, especially if this code worked before the update:

```
public IDataSource GetCategories()
{
    IDataSource reader = null;

    using (var cmd = MyDB.GetSqlStringCommand(MySqlScriptor.GetSql("QueryCategories")))
    {
        reader = (IDataSource)MyDB.ExecuteReader(cmd).InnerReader;
    }

    return reader;
}
```

But I have no environment that old to test with (And I have some really old code bases hanging around). Instead of executing a *Reader*, you can return a `DataSet` from the command using `ExecuteDataSet`, the `DataSet` then has an array of *DataTable* that you can return the first element from:

```
public IDataSource GetCategories()
{
    DataTable table = null;

    using (var cmd = MyDB.GetSqlStringCommand(MySqlScriptor.GetSql("QueryCategories")))
    {
        table = MyDB.ExecuteDataSet(cmd).Tables[0];
    }

    return table;
}
```